# Set default cache policy apollo swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo-client

Is there any way to set the default cache policy in Apollo framework in swift?

I know I can set cache policy for every fetch request by `cachePolicy` argument in this way:

```
Apollo.shared.client.fetch(query: getUser, cachePolicy: CachePolicy.fetchIgnoringCacheData)
```

But I'm looking for a way to set cache policy in `client` object for all requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code, there isn't such method or `cachePolicy` variable that you can set for ApolloClient.

You can create a singleton Apollo client class, and add your own fetch method with desired cachePolicy, like so

```
class ApolloManager {

    static let shared = Apollo()

    private var client: ApolloClient!
    var store: ApolloStore { return self.client.store }

    static func configure(url: URL, configuration: URLSessionConfiguration? = nil) {
        let store = ApolloStore(cache: InMemoryNormalizedCache())
        Apollo.shared.client = ApolloClient(networkTransport: HTTPNetworkTransport(url: url, configuration: configuration ?? .default), store: store)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func fetch<Query: GraphQLQuery>(query: Query, cachePolicy: CachePolicy = .fetchIgnoringCacheData, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, resultHandler: OperationResultHandler<Query>? = nil) -> Cancellable? {
        return self.client.fetch(query: query, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, queue: queue, resultHandler: resultHandler)
    }

}
```

**Initializer** can be added in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of AppDelegate.swift

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.4:2223")!
ApolloManager.configure(url: url)
```

You can also initialize your client with `configuration`

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "token"]
ApolloManager.configure(url: url, configuration: configuration)
```

**Usage**

```
ApolloManager.shared.fetch(query: getUser)
```

Comment: hi, can you update this answer for version 1.0